What is the easiest way of converting json to vector database
I need to convert a json file to vector database. I use chromadb.
collection.add(
    documents=["This is a document", "This is another document"],
    metadatas=[{"source": "my_source"}, {"source": "my_source"}],
    ids=["id1", "id2"]
)

This code is used to add a new data to the collection. How can I give a one big json file with complex fields(for example some fields has array values) to save into the collection. Or is there a better way to keep vector database rather than chromadb

Leveraging JSON input files containing both your interested field to create vector embeddings as well as other fields (e.g. non-searchable large text) you could always levarage the Data API of Astra DB. See this doc for getting started with it. You could index the required fields and leverage other fields to store large contents and get going! Also, check out this section of the docs to see the list of support field data types.

JSON Loader
One of the easiest way to read from one big json file with complex fields to save into a collection and load into Chroma DB is to use LangChain JSON Loader.
from langchain_community.document_loaders import JSONLoader

loader = JSONLoader(file_path="./data.json", jq_schema="your jq query here", text_content=False)
collection = loader.load()

JQ
You fetch data from json file together with jq_schema parameter that defines a JQ query.  JQ allows to slice, filter, map and transform structured data, in a similar way sed, awk, greps work for text.
Chroma DB
Finally here is an example of JSONLoader used for loading into Chroma DB from one json file with all-MiniLM-L6-v2 sentence transformer:
from langchain_community.document_loaders import JSONLoader
from langchain.embeddings.sentence_transformer import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma

loader = JSONLoader(file_path="./data.json", jq_schema="your jq query here", text_content=False)
collection = loader.load()

model = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")

db = Chroma.from_documents(collection, model)



The easiest way to convert your JSON Data is to first recursively split your JSONdata and store ChromaDb
for example:
from langchain_text_splitters import RecursiveJsonSplitter


def retrieve_data(docs) -> list[chroma.Document]:
    """
    Retrieve the data from the file

    Args: data: The data to be retrieved

    Returns: list: List of documents
    """

    for file in docs:
        with open(file, "r") as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())
            # Split the data into chunks
            splitter = RecursiveJsonSplitter(max_chunk_size=300)

            # create documents from the vector database
            documents = splitter.create_documents(texts=data, convert_lists=True)

    return documents

Then pass it to chromaDB
vectorstore_db = chroma.Chroma.from_documents(
    persist_directory="vectorstore_db",
    documents=retrieve_data(docs),
    embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings(),
)

vectorstore_db.persist()

vectordb = chroma.Chroma(
    persist_directory="vectorstore_db", embedding_function=OpenAIEmbeddings()
)
vector_retriever = vectordb.as_retriever()

